# Having trouble in understanding the definition of a clique

Tags: graphs, clique

My definition says

> A clique is a graph that has an edge connecting every pair of vertices

but as I understand, an edge connects only two vertices. Like $A-B$.

If we want to connect three vertices, we need at least two edges. For example, $A-B-C$.

I don't understand how an edge can connect every pair of vertices.

Comment: It's not one edge $e$ that connects all the pairs. For each pair $u,v\in V$ there is an edge $e_{uv}$ that connects the two nodes. That is, a clique is a (sub-)graph that contains all possible edges.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Recalling that a clique is a subset $C$ of vertices of an undirected graph such that the subgraph induced by $C$ is fully connected. That is, every two distinct  vertices in $C$ are connected by a **distinct edge** of the graph. This means different edges, not the same.

So, on a clique $C$ containing $k$ vertices $v_1, v_2,..,v_k$, there are $\frac{k(k-1)}2$ edges connecting them, that is the number of possible unordered pairs on $k$ elements.

### Example

[image]

As you can see in the previous picture, this is a clique on four vertices $\{{1,2,3,4}\}$, so there is a different edge connecting every edge (i.e. $(1,2)$,$(1,3)$,$(1,4)$,$(2,3)$,$(2,4)$,$(3,4)$).

You can count them and see that there are exactly $6 = \frac{4\times 3}{2}$ edges.

Comment: How do you know there are k(k-1)/2 edges?

Comment: For every 2 vertices there is an edge. How many pairs of vertices do you have from $n$? $\binom{n}{2}$